# What is the correct way to use queue.flush() and queue.finish() after calling a Kernel?

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl

I am using opencl 1.2 c++ wrapper for my project. I want to know what is the correct method to call my kernel. In my case, I have 2 devices and the data should be sent simultaneously to them.

I am dividing my data into two chunks and both the devices should be able to perform computations on them separately. They have no interconnection and they don't need to know what is happening in the other device.

When the data is sent to both the devices, I want to wait for the kernels to finish before my program goes further. Because I will be using results returned from both of the kernels. So I don't want to start reading the data before the kernels have returned.

I have 2 methods. Which one is programmatically correct in my case:

**Method 1:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
  // Enqueue the kernel.
  kernelGA(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue[iter],
                         arguments etc...);
  queue[i].flush();
}

// Wait for the kernels to return.
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
  queue[i].finish();
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
  // Enqueue the kernel.
  kernelGA(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue[iter],
                     arguments etc...);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
  queue[i].flush();
}

// Wait for the kernels to return.
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDevices; i++) {
  queue[i].finish();
}
```

Or none of them are correct and there is a better way to wait for my kernels to return?

Comment: Method 1 is the correct one. However you can do it better. Read the data back from the kernel in a non blocking wait. And then do the finish. That way both kernels can start copying the data back to host as soon as they finish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each device Computes in its own memory:

I would go for multi threaded (for) loop version of your method-1. Because opencl doesnt force vendors to do asynchronous enqueuing. Nvidia for example, does synchronous enqueuing for some drivers and hardware while amd has asynchronous enqueuing.

When each device is driven by a separate thread, they should enqueue Write+Compute together before synchronising for reading partial results(second threaded loop)

Having multiple threads also advantageous for spin-wait type synchronization (clfinish) because multiple spin-wait loops are worked in parallel. This should save time in Order of a millisecond.

Flush helps  some vendors like amd to start enqueueing Early.

To have correct input and correct output for all devices, only two finish commands are enough. One After Write+Compute then one After read(results). So each device get same time step data and produce results at same time step.  Write and Compute doesnt need finish between them if queue type is in-order because it Computes one by one. Also this doesnt need read operations to be blocking.

Trivial finish commands always Kill performance.

Note: I already wrote a load balancer using all this, and it performs better When using event-based synchronization instead of finish. Finish is easier but has bigger synchronization times than an event based one.

Also single queue doesnt always push a gpu to its limits. Using at Least 4 queues per device ensures Latency hiding of Write and Compute on my amd system. Sometimes even 16 queues help a bit more. But for io bottlenecked situations May need even more.

Example:

```
 thread1
      Write 
      Compute
      Synchronization with other thread

  Thread2
      Write
      Compute
      Synchronization with other thread




   Thread 1
         Read
         Synchronization with other thread

   Thread2
         Read
         Synchronization with other thread
```

Trivial synchronization Kills performance because drivers dont know your intention and they leave it as it is So you should elliminate unnecessary finish commands and convert blocking Writes to nonblocking ones where you can.

Zero synchronization is also wrong because opencl doesnt force vendors to start computing After several enqueues. It May indefinitely grow to gifabytes of memory in minutes or even seconds.

Comment: I am sorry but I am bound to use OpenCL.

Comment: Or it could be different opencl processes communicating with a ramdrive but pure threads is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Method 1. [clFlush](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clFlush.html) is the only way of guaranteeing that commands are issued to the device (and not just buffered somewhere before sending).